# {figure*} not displaying the figures in ieeetran?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I have three figures which i want to include over the full textwidth but only first is appearing.
I am using the code three times:
[image]

```
\begin{figure*}% not h only
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bothprofvc02.eps}%
    \caption{ROC curves for FVC2002 datasets}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}% not h only
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bothprofvc04.eps}%
        \caption{ROC curves for FVC2002 datasets}
    \end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}% not h only
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bothprofvc06.eps}%
        \caption{ROC curves for FVC2002 datasets}
    \end{figure*}
```

Comment: Your code shows only one instance of `figure*`. Is that the one that shows up without a problem? Please show the code for the other two `figure*` instances. Should all three instances of `figure*` fit on a single page, or should they be placed on separate pages?

Comment: Off-topic: Since the width of the image is set to `\textwidth`, the `\centering` directive has no effect and may be omitted.

Comment: Have you checked the next page?

Comment: @Johannes_B yes...i checked the next page also...

Comment: @Mico..I added three instances as what i am using..

Comment: Put the figures and the captions in one *single* `figure*` environment.

Comment: @Johannes_B...i have written some text in between. Actually explaining the figures in results and discussion section of manuscript

Comment: You've posted three identical `\caption` instructions. Is that also the case in your real document?

Comment: @Mico no, not the case in your real document..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all three graphs and their captions fit on a single page, you may want to implement @Johannes_B's advice and place the entire material in a single `figure*` environment:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bothprofvc02.eps}
    \caption{ROC curves for FVC2002 datasets}

\bigskip\bigskip

    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bothprofvc04.eps}
    \caption{ROC curves for FVC2004 datasets}

\bigskip\bigskip

    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bothprofvc06.eps}
    \caption{ROC curves for FVC2006 datasets}
\end{figure*}
```

At any rate, the following fully compilable code, which features three separate `figure*` environments, does not encounter a problem either in terms of the second and third figures disappearing. Please study *your* code -- of which you have posted only excerpts so far -- and determine if (rather: where) it contains instructions that are causing the problem.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]  % filler text
\begin{figure*}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.28\textheight]
        {bothprofvc02.eps}
    \caption{ROC curves for FVC2002 datasets}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.28\textheight]
        {bothprofvc04.eps}
    \caption{ROC curves for FVC2004 datasets}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.28\textheight]
        {bothprofvc06.eps}
    \caption{ROC curves for FVC2006 datasets}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[3-15] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still the issue persists...

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi - Please post the actual code that's giving you problems. What you've posted so far is not sufficiently informative.